# Set dtype of rasterio data upon reading

Tags: python, rasterio

I have the following piece of `rasterio` Python code, to read in a tiffs with discrete integer classes, which I mask immediately upon loading. I need finegrained control over the nodata value, which needs to be the same regardless of the input data type.

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.mask import mask

#[...]

    with rasterio.open(Geotiff_path) as src:
        cropped_image, _ = mask(src, 
                                POL, 
                                nodata=128,
                                crop=True,
                                all_touched=True
                               )
    return cropped_image.squeeze()
```

The problem is that if `print(src.dtypes)` is `int8`, the `nodata=128` overflows back to `-128`. Of course, one fix is to simply use `nodata=127`. However, I would prefer it if it were possible to return the `cropped_image` with a different dtype such as `int16`, wherein the `nodata` didn't overflow.

Note that doing `cropped_image.squeeze().astype(np.uint16)` does the transformation too late, i.e., the overflow of the `nodata` value to -128 already happened. So the question is: how can I read in the rasterio grid (or the masked version) with a different dtype than the original grid reports?

I'm using `rasterio==1.2.10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't specify `nodata=128`. If `filled=False`, `mask` returns a [`np.ma.MaskedArray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) which you can cast to `np.uint16` then set all values to 128 where the mask is `True`:

```
import fiona
import rasterio
from rasterio.mask import mask

with fiona.open("/tmp/mask.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open("/tmp/test.tif") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = mask(src, shapes, crop=True, filled=False, all_touched=True)
    data = out_image.data.astype('uint16')
    data[out_image.mask] = 128
```

Alternatively, use a [WarpedVRT](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.vrt.html) to alter dtype on the fly:

```
import fiona
import rasterio
from rasterio.mask import mask
from rasterio.vrt import WarpedVRT

with fiona.open("/tmp/mask.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with WarpedVRT(rasterio.open("/tmp/test.tif"), dtype='uint16') as vrt:
    out_image, out_transform = mask(vrt, shapes, nodata=128, crop=True, all_touched=True)
```